# item within flexbox column is not sticky

Tags: flexbox, sticky

I try to let a menu bar within a header stay sticky. The header is a flexbox with vertical align (flex-direction: column). But as you may guess, it does not work.

**simplified arrangement**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jANmM.png)

**HTML**

```html
<header>
    <div id="quality-logos">
       [some images here]
    </div>
    <div id="logo_motte_top">
        [a big logo here]
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-wrapper">
        <div id="navigation">
            [some navigation code here]
        </div>
        <div id="menu_promo_text">
            <div>Mo – Sa: 09 – 18 Uhr, So nach Vereinbarung</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS (shortened)**

```css
header{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
div#navigation-wrapper{
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
}
```

You can see it live at [motteduesseldorf.de](http://motteduesseldorf.de/was-gibts-im-caf%C3%A9)

Answer (score 0):

For your [website's link](https://motteduesseldorf.de/), your `<header>` is a child of another div called `#wrapper`. `position: sticky` is probably being applied but it is not visible because the entire `<header>` div is not in view. Put another way, `position: sticky` works only "until" its immediate parent.

One way to fix your issue would be to move `<div id="navigation-wrapper">` outside of `<header>` and make it an immediate child of the `<div id="wrapper">`.